# When user first time lauch app, LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient) returns null

Tags: android

my app needs to track user current location. i am doing this using LocationServices FusedLocationApi. Problem is when user install my app and launch app, my app does not able to track user location. this issue comes only first time. then after whenever my app open that activity, i am not getting any problem. my app is able to track user location.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                Log.d(APP_TAG,"A");

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Display UI and wait for user interaction
            } else {
                // Check Permissions Now
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }

            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return;
        }
        //DevicePreferences.getGoogleApiClient().connect();

        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLocationAvailability(mGoogleApiClient);

             /*mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);*/



            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);




        Log.d(APP_TAG,""+mLastLocation);












        /*while (mLastLocation == null){

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
        }*/


        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            changeMap(mLastLocation);
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "ON connected");

        } else
           try {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "B");

               LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

                /*LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, this);*/

           } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000); //10000
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); //5000

           // mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d(APP_TAG,"4");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize your **mGoogleApiClient**, if you haven't already, like this :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

if, there is any other problem then kindly describe in detail, with more code